# Aggregating rows in SQL with missing Booleans

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have the below SQL script which returns the following data from a **PostgreSQL** DB view table.

```
SELECT 
  "V_data".macaddr,
  "V_data".sensorid,
  "V_data".ts,
  "V_data".velocity,
  "V_data".temp,
  "V_data".highspeed,
  "V_data".hightemp,
  "V_data".distance,

FROM 
  sensordb."V_data"

WHERE 
  "V_data".macaddr like '%abcdef'

AND
  (
  ("V_data".sensorid = 'abc1') or ("V_data".sensorid = 'a2bc') or ("V_data".sensorid = 'ab3c') 
  )

AND
  "V_data".ts >= 1616370867000

ORDER BY
  "V_data".ts DESC;
```

**Output**

| macaddr | sensorid | ts | velocity | temp | highspeed | hightemp | distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcdef | abc1 | 1616370867010 | 25 | 32 |  |  | 52 |
| abcdef | a2bc | 1616370867008 | 27 | 35 |  | T | 51 |
| abcdef | ab3c | 1616370867006 | 26 | 30 |  |  | 50 |
| abcdef | abc1 | 1616370867005 | 24 | 36 |  | T | 50 |
| abcdef | a2bc | 1616370867004 | 27 | 31 |  |  | 50 |
| abcdef | abc1 | 1616370867002 | 21 | 30 | T |  | 48 |
| abcdef | ab3c | 1616370867000 | 22 | 33 | F |  | 46 |

I want to aggregate the rows such that I have the latest readings per sensorid for ts, velocity, temp, distance.
***For the Booleans highspeed and hightemp, I want the latest available Boolean value or an empty cell if no Boolean value was available.***

**Expected output**

| macaddr | sensorid | ts | velocity | temp | highspeed | hightemp | distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcdef | abc1 | 1616370867010 | 25 | 32 | T | T | 52 |
| abcdef | a2bc | 1616370867008 | 27 | 35 |  | T | 51 |
| abcdef | ab3c | 1616370867006 | 26 | 30 | F |  | 50 |

How could I simplify this task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT ON` (available only in PostgreSQL afaik) to simplify this query. You can do:

```
with
q as (
  -- your query here
)
select 
  l.macaddr, l.sensorid, l.ts, l.velocity, l.temp,
  s.highspeed, t.hightemp, 
  l.distance  
from (
  select distinct on (sensorid) *
  from q
  order by sensorid, ts desc
) l
left join (
  select distinct on (sensorid) *
  from q
  where highspeed is not null
  order by sensorid, ts desc
) s on s.sensorid = l.sensorid
left join (
  select distinct on (sensorid) *
  from q
  where hightemp is not null
  order by sensorid, ts desc
) t on t.sensorid = l.sensorid
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm . . . For all but the boolean columns `DISTINCT ON` would work.  But those booleans are tricky.  You *could* use some tricks on booleans.

Instead, let's go for `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the most recent row.  And fiddle with arrays to get the most recent boolean values:

```
SELECT d.macaddr, d.sensorid,
       MAX(d.ts) as ts,
       MAX(d.velocity) FILTER (WHERE seqnum = 1) as velocity,
       MAX(d.temp) FILTER (WHERE seqnum = 1) as temp,
       (ARRAY_REMOVE(ARRAY_AGG(d.highspeed ORDER BY ts DESC), NULL))[1] as highspeed,
       (ARRAY_REMOVE(ARRAY_AGG(d.hightemp ORDER BY ts DESC), NULL))[1] as hightemp
       MAX(d.distance) FILTER (WHERE seqnum = 1)
FROM (SELECT d.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.macaddr, d.sensorid ORDER BY ts DESC) as seqnum
      FROM sensordb."V_data" d
      WHERE d.macaddr like '%abcdef' AND
            d.sensorid IN ('abc1', 'a2bc', 'ab3c') AND
            d.ts >= 1616370867000
     ) d
GROUP BY d.macaddr, d.sensorid
ORDER BY d.ts DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. With minor modifications to your code, I was able to get the result. You also gave me a new perspective to look at it using the ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: @aj7amigo . . . How does the performance of this compare to using multiple `JOIN`s.  I was trying to avoid joins for performance reasons.

Comment: At the moment, the amount of rows in the database is very less (under 1000). So I don't see a difference in the execution time. The code from you and @The Impaler works in under 1 second. But I will keep an eye on it as the data grows over time. Thanks a lot for the hint. Cheers.